# Compare effect of resection extent on survival in two types of tumors

Tags: survival, treatment-effect

I have two groups of patients with similar, but different brain tumors (tumor type 1 and 2 for simplicity). All underwent surgery, the achieved extent of resection over a certain cutoff value should prolong the survival (and does, in the whole group). Now I would like to quantify the effect of the extent of resection in each group and compare these effects.

H1 The effect of the radical tumor resection is more pronounced in tumor type 2 than in tumor type 1.

How could this be proven ideally? This should be basic, comparing the effect of one treatment in two types of disease, but I cannot find the right answer.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Amir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a significance test of the *interaction* between the tumor type and the extent of resection. All standard statistical software provides for such a test. Your model would then have (at least) 3 predictor variables: the tumor type, the extent of resection, and their interaction.

Your application here, however, raises some cautions. First, survival analysis requires about 15 events (presumably deaths here) per variable entered into the model. So even your simplest model would need information on enough cases to include about 50 events.

Second, a clinical study typically should account for other clinical characteristics like age, prior therapy, overall health status, and in this case perhaps tumor extent before surgery. Each variable added to the model requires an additional 15 cases to avoid overfitting, although techniques like propensity scores can be used to combine information about several clinical characteristics into a single variable for your analysis.

Third, you say that there is a "cutoff" in resection extent that is related to outcome. Presumably there is some underlying continuous relation of resection to outcome, so use of a strict cutoff is throwing away potentially useful information. If the value of the cutoff was determined from outcomes in this data set, there is the additional problem that you have violated the assumptions necessary to interpret *p*-values properly.

Finally there is the issue of interpretation. My guess is that surgeons attempt to remove as much tumor as is compatible with reasonably functional life in all cases. The interaction you are investigating thus might just be a proxy for differences between the two types of tumor in terms of things like clinically undetectable spread beyond resection margins. Thus if you do find a statistically significant interaction discussion of its clinical significance would require a good deal of care.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have approximately 80 cases total. However these are ~60 Type 1 tumors and ~20 Type 2 tumors, type 2 is rare. But, there are ~ 45 events in Type 1 and ~15 in Type 2.